# use of unresolved identifier 'info' apple tutorial

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on this app development tutorial:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW1

and I got up to the part where you use the info dictionary (towards the end of the tutorial), but I'm getting the error "use of unresolved identifier 'info'". I copied and pasted the code they provided:

```
//The info dictionary contains multiple representations of the image,
//and this uses the original.
let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
```

but it wont work

Answer (score 0):

The code is supposed to be placed in this method:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, 
                           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
}
```

`info` is one of the parameters to the function.